# How to secure a PHPMailer file

Tags: php, security, phpmailer

Just finished doing a simple mail transfer at my site using [PhpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

I got 3 question about it -

1. I have read that's needed to store your credentials on a different file, read that there's 2 options - ini/php, which one would be better and how exactly this file should look like.
2. Regarding the directory of the credentials file, read it should be located outside the web root (just one level above its fine?), in that case how do I call it from inside the web root?
3. On the same matter, should the **Mail.php** itself be located on the site directory? or should I take it out as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's generally safest to put values like these in `.php` files because they will render to nothing, unlike a `.ini` file which will usually render as plain text.
2. Yes, one level above is fine - it means that the file does not have a public URL of its own. From a script running inside the web root, you'd just load it with `require '../settings.php';`
3. You don't say what Mail.php is, but generally any other PHP scripts can stay put. Things like class definitions are safe because they have no effect when run directly (or at least *should have* no effect, if you've written them safely!). That said, it's common to put your composer `vendor` folder outside the web root since you don't necessarily have control over what ends up in there.

Comment: Hey thanks alot!, iv'e done some changes since. 
and currently doing it like so - 

$path = realpath('credentials.ini');
$config = parse_ini_file($path, true);
        $mail->Username = $config['username'];          
        $mail->Password = $config['password'];

Is it necessary to replace the .ini file with .php? as Iv'e seen all over people recommending .ini

Comment: Also, is this a correct understanding of the server  ? 

Server Root > includes everything and not accessiable from web. 
Document Root > (Located inside Server Root) Public Files accessiable from web?

Comment: It will work either way - There's no advantage of using an ini file I can think of; it just adds a processing step to store the same info, so you may as well just keep it in PHP. And yes, your understanding of the file layout looks right; you can stick your settings file in the server root and access it from scripts in the web root.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help!